# variadic template recursion with sizeof..., but compile error: no matching function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I write a variadic template to print all the arguments with recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream; using std::istream;
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
ostream &myprint(ostream &os, const T &t, const Args&... rest) {
    if (sizeof...(rest)) {
        os << t << ", ";
        return myprint(os, rest...);
    }
    else
        return os << t;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    myprint(cout, "hello");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compiles it with `g++ -std=c++1y`, it complains:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘myprint(std::ostream&)’
     return myprint(os, rest...);
```

In the function `myprint`, I have checked the value of `sizeof...(rest)`. And when it is 0, it will not call `myprint(os, rest...)`. So I don't know why it will call `myprint(std::ostream&)`.

And I have also searched for the related question, I have found that it needs a *base case*. But why do I need a base case, and can't `sizeof...` work in a variadic template?

And for the simple indefinite recursive case:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
ostream &myprint(ostream &os, const T &t, const Args&... rest) {
    os << t << ", ";            // print the first argument
    return print(os, rest...);  // recursive call; print the other arguments
}
```

The code above can't be compiled at all for the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the [if statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) you used, both the *statement-true* and *statement-false* must be valid, whether the *condition* yields to the result of `true` or `false`.

You can use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) since C++17; when the value of *condition* is `false`, the *statement-true* will be discarded. e.g.

```
if constexpr (sizeof...(rest)) {
    os << t << ", ";
    return myprint(os, rest...);
}
else
    return os << t;
```

If you can't use C++17, you can add another template overload for the case that the number of arguments is only one, to stop the recursion, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
ostream &myprint(ostream &os, const T &t) {
    return os << t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
ostream &myprint(ostream &os, const T &t, const Args&... rest) {
    os << t << ", ";
    return myprint(os, rest...);
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/NMVO82760)

Comment: Thank you. But how does the compiler compiles all the path of the code in simple words? And maybe my compiler doesn't support C++17.

Comment: @zhenguoli It means, the statements must be valid even if it never gets executed.

Comment: @zhenguoli Answer revised.

Comment: Thanks. I may have got it. But my compiler doesn't support C++17 feature. So is the only way that I can make the variadic templates works is construct a base case?

Comment: @zhenguoli Yes. You have to add an overload for only one argument; to stop the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

[songyuanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46386901/4832499) explains why it's invalid and provides a solution for C++17. Alternatively, you could have a base case to `myprint` prior to that.

```
template <typename T>
ostream &myprint(ostream &os, const T &t) {
    return os << t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
ostream &myprint(ostream &os, const T &t, const Args&... rest) {
    os << t << ", ";
    return myprint(os, rest...);
}
```